# Switch Statement in Android OnClickListener

Tags: android, switch-statement, onclicklistener

I am working in Android, trying to set OnClickListeners for 10 buttons. I can get the code to work how I want it to if I write out every button's action in the switch statement, but it is a lot of work for just a tiny change in each. Is there a way to use a loop to iterate through the cases of a switch?

The code below will not compile, error at "case i" says "case expressions must be constant expressions".

```
private OnClickListener buttonListener = new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(final View v) {
         for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
             switch(v.getId()) {
             case i:
                 for(int j = 0; j < numberOfPlayers; j++) {
                     if(playersArray[j].isChecked()) {
                         playerScores[j] += i;
                         playersArray[j].setScore(Integer.toString(playerScores[i]));
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
};
```

and this code is what I am trying to avoid doing, but nevertheless will compile and run correctly:

```
private OnClickListener buttonListener = new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(final View v) {
         switch(v.getId()) {
         case 0:
             for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
                 if(playersArray[i].isChecked()) {
                     playerScores[i] += possibleValue[0];
                     playersArray[i].setScore(Integer.toString(playerScores[i]));
                 }
             }
             break;
         case 1:
             for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
                 if(playersArray[i].isChecked()) {
                     playerScores[i] += possibleValue[1];
                     playersArray[i].setScore(Integer.toString(playerScores[i]));
                 }
             }
             break;
         case ... :
         }
     }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want:

```
private OnClickListener buttonListener = new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(final View v) {
         for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
             if (v.getId() == i) {
                 for(int j = 0; j < numberOfPlayers; j++) {
                     if(playersArray[j].isChecked()) {
                         playerScores[j] += i;
                         playersArray[j].setScore(Integer.toString(playerScores[i]));
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
};
```

or, if I understand your logic, this more direct approach should work equally well:

```
private OnClickListener buttonListener = new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(final View v) {
         int i = v.getId();
         for(int j = 0; j < numberOfPlayers; j++) {
             if(playersArray[j].isChecked()) {
                 playerScores[j] += i;
                 playersArray[j].setScore(Integer.toString(playerScores[i]));
             }
         }
     }
};
```

Comment: That last one is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!